# Not getting warning messages with go build

Tags: go

```
// test.go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%s", 0) // format error
}
```

With `go build test.go` I got no warning messages or errors at all. I don't see a warning flag in `go help build` either. Am I missing something?

Comment: `go test` runs `vet` automatically; build doesn't.